# Fail to Generate Binary Output

Tags: matlab, simulink, mbed

I was using MATLAB simulink to run some examples on FRDM-KL25Z board and I was unable to deploy any of the examples into the hardware.
One of the examples prompted me error and I have attached along with the attachment.

Do I need to install any third-party software such as Kinetis Design Studio to deploy the library to the board? [Error File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaOui.png)

Comment: Your compiler try to access to the mbed library (mbed.h) but cannot find the file, so of course it won't work. So just download the mbed library.

Comment: Hi I have added the headers and C file into the directory but now another error pop out [link](http://i.imgur.com/FrIYnTx.png?1) . It shows that .../TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/libmbed.a',needed by ".../freedomboard_potServo.elf'. @obchardon Any idea?